# Trying to subistitute values of a column of a dataframe with the values of another dataframe when common lines of a column are present, but no result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe

```
db
index| Line Item | Creative Size
1    | AA        | Size1
2    | BB        | Unknown
3    | CC        | Unknown

df1
index| Line Item | Size
1    | BB        | Size2
2    | CC        | Size3
```

When Line Item code is the same, I want to substitute the value of Creative Size with the value of Size.
My expected output is:

```
db:
index| Line Item | Creative Size
1    | AA        | Size1
2    | BB        | Size2
3    | CC        | Size3
```

Note that the size of df1 is less than the one of db.

I come up with:

```
rename_dict = df2.set_index('Line Item').to_dict()['Size']
db['Creative Size'] = db['Creative Size'].replace(rename_dict)
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.
Any help? Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by column `Line Item` and non matched values replace by original by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
db['Creative Size'] = db['Line Item'].map(rename_dict).fillna(db['Creative Size'])
```